# IndexedDB takes time to initialize outer scope variable db which is needed in another function

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am opening a database using indexedDB using javascript for keeping a diary entry. I am doing three things with the database: display all entry, add entry, and remove entry.

It fails when it tries to create a transaction because 'db' is 'undefined.' I was expecting db to be defined by the time the code tries to create a transaction.

Error is caused at the line with code:

```
      const getObjectStore = (storeName, mode) => {
        console.log('db: ', db);
        const tx = db.transaction(storeName, mode); // error is thrown because db is undefined
        return tx.objectStore(storeName);
      };
```

I tried to put console.log at different places to see what is wrong. I found that db takes time before it gets defined by an onsuccess response or onupgradeneeded response. I don't see any other way to define db before it is used. Can you show me how I can assure myself for the assignment of db before it is used?

Outputs:

```
> adding something in the diary
> db from getObjectStore:  undefined
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined
    at getObjectStore (script.js:35)
    at Object.setAnEntry [as add] (script.js:62)
    at script.js:81
    at script.js:215
getObjectStore @ script.js:35
setAnEntry @ script.js:62
(anonymous) @ script.js:81
(anonymous) @ script.js:215
> there is indexeddb!
> db:  IDBDatabase {name: "medDiary", version: 1, objectStoreNames: DOMStringList, onabort: null, onclose: null, …}
```

All the code i am working with:

```
  // DATABASE FOR THE DIARY

  const Dairy = (() => {
    if (window.indexedDB) {
      let db;
      const DB_NAME = 'Dairy';
      const DB_VERSION = 1;
      const DB_STORE_NAME = 'diaries';
      const request = window.indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION);

      request.onerror = () => {
        console.log('Error requesting to open database permission denied.');
      };
      request.onsuccess = (event) => {
        console.log('there is indexeddb!');
        db = event.target.result;
        console.log('db: ', db);
        db.onerror = (evt) => {
          console.error(`Database error: ${evt.target.errorCode}`);
        };
      };

      request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
        db = request.result;
        const store = event.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, { keyPath: 'date' });
        store.createIndex('subject', 'subject', { unique: false });
        store.createIndex('date', 'date', { unique: true });
        store.createIndex('description', 'description', { unique: false });
      };

      const getObjectStore = (storeName, mode) => {
        console.log('db from getObjectStore: ', db);
        const tx = db.transaction(storeName, mode);
        return tx.objectStore(storeName);
      };

      const getAllEntries = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
        const result = [];
        const store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readonly');
        const req = store.openCursor();

        req.onsuccess = (evt) => {
          const cursor = evt.target.result;

          if (cursor) {
            const retrive = store.get(cursor.key);
            retrive.onsuccess = function (evt) {
              const value = evt.target.result;
              result.append(value);
            };
            cursor.continue();
          } else {
            console.log('No more entries');
            resolve(result);
          }
        };
      });

      const setAnEntry = (value) => {
        const store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');
        store.put(value);
      };
      const removeAnEntry = (value) => {
        const store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');
        store.remove(value);
      };

      return {
        all: getAllEntries,
        add: setAnEntry,
        remove: removeAnEntry,
      };
    }
    alert("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB. Dairy related features will not be available.");
    return {};
  })();

  console.log('adding something in the diary');
  console.log('... ', Dairy.add({ subject: 'hello', description: 'bluh bluh', date: Date() }));
  console.log('show all: ', Dairy.all());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of null with an indexeddb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256202/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-transaction-of-null-with-an-indexeddb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a promise to open the DB:

```
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
        {
            //check for support
            if (!('indexedDB' in window)) {
                //console.log('This browser doesn\'t support IndexedDB');
                reject("indexedDB not supported");
            }

            var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, dbVersion);
            request.onerror = function (event) {
                reject("Error opening DB");
            };
            request.onsuccess = function (event) {
                console.log("opened!");
                db = request.result;
                resolve(true);
            };
        });
```

And then you can use:

```
promise
    .then(
        result => {
            your stuff here sine the DB is now open!!
        },
        error => console.log(error)
    )
```

The parameter passed to resolve will be available as 'result'.

To use in your module format:
Add init function:

```
async function init()
{
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
        {
            //check for support
            if (!('indexedDB' in window)) {
                //console.log('This browser doesn\'t support IndexedDB');
                reject("indexedDB not supported");
            }

            var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, dbVersion);
            request.onerror = function (event) {
                reject("Error opening DB");
            };
            request.onsuccess = function (event) {
                console.log("opened!");
                db = request.result;
                resolve(true);
            };
        });
    let result = await promise;
}
```

Your module rewritten:

```
const Dairy = (() => {
    if (window.indexedDB)
    {
        let db;
        const DB_NAME = 'Dairy';
        const DB_VERSION = 1;
        const DB_STORE_NAME = 'diaries';
        async function init()
        {
            let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
            {
                const request = window.indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION);

                request.onerror = () => {
                    reject('Error requesting to open database permission denied.');
                };
                request.onsuccess = (event) => {
                    console.log('there is indexeddb!');
                    db = event.target.result;
                    console.log('db: ', db);
                    db.onerror = (evt) => {
                        reject("Database error: ${evt.target.errorCode}");
                    };
                    resolve(true);
                };

                request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
                    db = request.result;
                    const store = event.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, { keyPath: 'date' });
                    store.createIndex('subject', 'subject', { unique: false });
                    store.createIndex('date', 'date', { unique: true });
                    store.createIndex('description', 'description', { unique: false });
                };
            });
            return promise;
        }

      const getObjectStore = (storeName, mode) => {
        console.log('db from getObjectStore: ', db);
        const tx = db.transaction(storeName, mode);
        return tx.objectStore(storeName);
      };

      const getAllEntries = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
        const result = [];
        const store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readonly');
        const req = store.openCursor();

        req.onsuccess = (evt) => {
          const cursor = evt.target.result;

          if (cursor) {
            const retrive = store.get(cursor.key);
            retrive.onsuccess = function (evt) {
              const value = evt.target.result;
              result.append(value);
            };
            cursor.continue();
          } else {
            console.log('No more entries');
            resolve(result);
          }
        };
      });

      const setAnEntry = (value) => {
        const store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');
        store.put(value);
      };
      const removeAnEntry = (value) => {
        const store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');
        store.remove(value);
      };

      return {
        all: getAllEntries,
        add: setAnEntry,
        remove: removeAnEntry,
        init: init
      };
    }
    alert("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB. Dairy related features will not be available.");
    return {};
  })();
  Dairy.init()
    .then(
        result => {
            console.log('adding something in the diary');
            console.log('... ', Dairy.add({ subject: 'hello', description: 'bluh bluh', date: Date() }));
            console.log('show all: ', Dairy.all());
        },
        error => console.log(error)
    );
```

Comment: i am trying to use the module pattern, i have to return an object that is set to Diary. How would do i return a value from then() to get set to Diary?

Comment: make yourself an init function for your module. like async function init(). inside you can use: let result = await promise; this will wait for the promise to end. i will update answer

Comment: I don't understand how the async function init() is used or incorporated with your previous answer. where would i put the functions that add and delete from the database? I understand upto using promise and doing then on the promise. you lost me at async.

Comment: check my answer and try please

Comment: I see what you did there. It works but I have to call init and in then use database everytime I have to use the database. Though, maybe I do that for the first time and carry on normal invoking outside then with proceeding database interaction. 

If I copied the code to external file and import it with out the module patter, it works okay, which looks nice. But I learned a lot from your answer. Thank you!