# indexedDB: issue calling transaction function

Tags: indexeddb, sencha-touch-2.3

I am new to IndexedDB and sencha touch framework. 
While learning IndexedDB in sencha, I came across a problem, the solution which I searched a lot but could not find any.

**Let me show you my chunk of code first**

```
        var db;
        var myRequest = indexedDB.open("testDB", 8);

        myRequest.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
            console.log("upgrading...");
            var thisDB= e.target.result;
            if(!thisDB.objectStoreNames.contains("FirstOS")){
            thisDB.createObjectStore("FirstOS");
            }
        };

        myRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
            console.log("success...");
            db= e.target.result;
        };

        myRequest.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log("error occured");
        };


    var transaction = db.transaction(["FirstOS"],"readwrite");
    var store= transaction.objectStore("FirstOS");
```

It throws an exception saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is not specific to using indexedDB. The call to `indexedDB.db.transaction()` is what generates this error message. This error happens when you try and call a method of an object that is not initialized. To avoid this error, do not use `var db` outside of the scope of the onsuccess callback function. Do not try to use `db=event.target.result;`.

This error occurs because you are probably not familiar with asynchronous functions. You will need to learn more about how to write asynchronous code before continuing to use indexedDB.

This question is a duplicate of several similar questions:

- [IndexedDB not working in Firefox 29, but in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370250)
- [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of null with an indexeddb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256202)
- [Why is db.transaction not working with indexeddb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148299)
- [Is it bad to open several database connections in indexedDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418954)
- [Why is onupgradeneeded never called in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434218)

Comment: Actually I mistakenly posted the wrong version of code.
I have edited it now.
Thanks well, I would learn about Asynchronous function. Thanks .